# How to generate and use the same Google Meet link for events for multiple Google calendars

Tags: google-apps-script

Right now I have a Google spreadsheet that will take any row of event information and create an event in the Google calendar using the Google's apps script. The script will create the same event in 3 different calendars but the problem is that the Google Meet link is different for all three events. I need to have the link the same because I need to have all the guests from each calendar join the same link from the calendar event.

Is there a way!?

Thanks

Comment: Share you current script.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no possible way of setting the Meet link for an event programmatically as the `hangoutLink` field associated to a meeting is read-only.

This essentially means that you **cannot** change the Meet link associated with the event created, nor assign a custom one to it.

> `hangoutLink` > An absolute link to the Google+ hangout associated with this event. **Read-only**.

This is also reflected in the Apps Script methods as the `CalendarEvent` class does not have a method of setting the Meet link for an event.

What you can do in this situation however is to star ★ the issue for the Calendar API on Google Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/36760708) **or** create a new one in the Apps Script component [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113).

#### Reference

- [Calendar API Events Resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource).
- [Apps Script CalendarEvent Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event).